# Добавление данных в БД с помощью ajax

Tags: php, javascript

На форме есть 3 поля, необходимо добавить их в БД без перезагрузки страницы.
Форма с скриптом:

```
    <form id="myform" action="#" method="post" >
                                        <div class="trading__buy-row">
                                            <div class="trading__buy-row-title">Price</div>
                                            <input type="text" id="price" name="price" class="priceField" onchange=f()>
                                            <div class="trading__buy-row-title2">BTC</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="trading__buy-row">
                                            <div class="trading__buy-row-title">Amount</div>
                                            <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" class="amountField" onchange=f()>
                                            <div class="trading__buy-row-title2">ETH</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="trading__buy-row">
                                            <div class="trading__buy-row-title">Total</div>
                                            <input type="text" id="total" name="total" class="totalField" >
                                            <div class="trading__buy-row-title2">BTC</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="trading__buy-text">Trade commission: <span>0.1%</span></div>
                                        <!--<div class="btn btn--buy" id="sub" >BUY ETH</div> -->
                                        <input type="submit" value="Buy" class="button">
                                        <span id="result"></span>
                                    </form>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".button").bind("click", function() {

        var price = jQuery('.priceField').val();
        var amount = jQuery('.amountField').val();
        var total = jQuery('.totalField').val();

        jQuery('.priceField').val('');
        jQuery('.amountField').val('');
        jQuery('.totalField').val('');

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "for_db.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {price:price, amount:amount, total: total}, // Передаем данные для записи
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                if (result){ 
                    alert ('jQuery подключен и отлично работает!');
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

For_db.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
    include_once('db.php');
    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        $sesion_id=$_SESSION['userid'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$amount =$_POST['amount'];
$total = $_POST['total'];
}
/** Если нам передали ID то обновляем */
if($price && $amount && $total){
    //вставляем запись в БД
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `ordersbuy` (`id`,`price`,`amount`,`total`) VALUES ('$sesion_id','$price','$amount','$total')");
}
?>
```

Но после нажатия на кнопку, кроме очистки полей ничего не происходит

Comment: Может следует указывать полный путь к странице запроса?

Comment: @MrBin вы про action в форме? указал for_db.php но толку нте

Comment: Знает кто в чем дело?

Comment: Да, я про него. Но ведь у вас есть web сервер? Если есть, то обращения идут через него. Лучше указать полный адрес типа: `http:\\localhost:8080\for_db.php`